# Does headless chrome driver close automatically if error?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, headless-browser

when I run normal chrome driver, if an error occurs before the .close(), I will have to close the driver manually. 
Will headless chrome driver close itself if error? I don't want 100 drivers running in the background without me knowing. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. 
If you will use:

```
try:
    some_hacking_shit_you_doing()
except:
    WebDriver.Chrome().quit
```

Your chrome will close itself. But it depends what error you have. If i remember some exceptions has close function, some will just crash and continue to eat your ram.

Comment: Thanks I probably will use the try/except method.